# react-native cannot get updated apk

Tags: react-native, gradlew

I use last version of react and react-native on Windows 10 OS.

I have a strange behavior when i try to run my code on phone or to compile debug apk.

*1. Run on the phone*

`> react-native run-android`

the process run `gradlew` building (i think) , i get on the phone an OLD version of my code while this step is not finished

[image]

When it finished  another console with node automatically open with `loading dependency graph`and a `bundling` step is done ( Bundling `index.android.js`  [development, non-minified]  100.0% (960/960), done.) after that my apps on the phone get refreshed with latest code .

[image]

maybe it is the regular senario case i don't know.

---

*2. Compile APK*

i run
`> react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug`

`> cd android/`

`> ./gradlew assembleDebug`

i get the apk `android\app\build\outputs\apk\app-x86-debug.apk`
I install it on the phone or virtual emulator , but i get THE OLD version of my code and note the latest so cannot send it to other tester.

What i'm doing wrong ?

PS : I try to clean with gradlew `>cd android ; ./gradlew clean ;` before compiling.  same results

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already compiled APK on your device, you **don't need** to recompile (*do the `react-native run-android`*) **again** from your computer. In case you updated the JAVA source code, you need to recompile it.

To update the app, simply press *RELOAD* on debugging menu in your app.
See this for more information: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

On react-native we also have **HOT RELOADING**, which can update your UI instantly after you save the code.

Comment: thanks for reply, I cannot just reload the app because if i unplug/plug the phone i always have error message : "could not connect to developement server" so i have to make "react-native run android" each time i plug it. of course i plug it only few time per day, so i refresh app most of the time ;)

Comment: Then you should set your own ip, so you don't have to connected with cables anymore, See this for more info: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.21/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-your-app-to-connect-to-the-local-dev-server-via-wi-fi

Answer (score 0):

First of all, close all terminals running React server.

1 Go to Android Folder and Delete Build folder.

2 Delete watchman cache if you are using watchman - watchman watch-del-all

3 Clean npm cache - npm start -- --reset-cache

After this, ensure you have enable Debug JS Remotely in the React native's menu.

It happened to me and that is what I remember what I did.
I hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade Expo CLI and run `exp publish` before each `gradlew assembleRelease`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.If **cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease** is not working.
Check this file **android/app/build.gradle**.
If this key "**signingConfigs**" exist or not if not add it.
See here- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android 
and run command- **react-native start --reset-cache** and **cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease**